# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I get error below. I know what this code means but I do not know how interface should look like:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

interfaces:

```
export declare interface Category {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    parent_id: string;
}

export declare interface CategoriesMap {
    [key: string]: Category;
}
```

component:

```
private listOfSubcategories: CategoriesMap[] = [];

private selectCategory($event: any, index: string) {
        this.category = this.listOfSubcategories[index][$event.target.value];
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Your `this.listOfSubcategories` is an array, but `index` is a string. This should be a number to read from the array.

Comment: Thanks. But Now

let foo = this.subcategories[parseInt(index)]
foo.filter((d :any) => true);

throws

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Comment: Why have you typed `d` as `any`? Will it not be `CategoriesMap`?

Comment: Yes but 'any' is safer. The full error is: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Category' has no compatible call signatures.